# Loop to insert unique rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets, each with a list of accounts.

I need to create one worksheet, that combines the two lists, with unique values. **Everything needs to stay in order.**

I'm trying to write VBA that will find unique values in one list and insert them in the other.

```vb
Sub Consolidate()

    Dim PYWks As Worksheet
    Dim CYWks As Worksheet
    Set PYWks = Sheets("Prior Year")
    Set CYWks = Sheets("Current Year")

    Dim I As Long
    Dim InsertRange As Range
    Set InsertRange = PYWks.Range("B:B")

    NRows = CYWks.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next

    For I = 5 To NRows
        InsertX = CYWks.Range("B" & I).Value
        PYWks.Range("InsertRange").Cells.Find("Insert X").EntireRow.Resize(InsertX.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next I

End Sub
```

My idea is to match the two lists, and if I get an error (a unique value) I could use the value from the row above it to find the location on the second list.

Comment: Putting the name inside quotes like `PYWks.Range("InsertRange")` would refer to a *named range* on the worksheet. To refer to your declared variable range you just write it `InsertRange`. So your line should be `InsertRange.Cells.Find(....`

Comment: Similarly, in your `.Find` method. You are looking for `"Insert X"` which is a literal string. To use your dynamic variable value, you should not have quotes and should write your declared variable name `InsertX`. So the method should be written like `.Find(InsertX)....`

Comment: To copy and paste rows into the worksheet, you can use `Range1.EntireRow.Copy` and `Range2.EntireRow.Insert`. The Range would be fully inserted, maintaining the row order of the original sheet contained.